# W/FirebaseMessaging(26414): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying push notification it is logging me this error:

> W/FirebaseMessaging(26414): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
  import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
  import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';

void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
  }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
 final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

 MyApp() {
_configureFirebaseMessaging();
 }

 void _configureFirebaseMessaging() {
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("onMessage: $message");
  _logNotificationReceivedEvent();
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");
  _logNotificationOpenedAppEvent();
});

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
_firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
  sound: true,
  badge: true,
  alert: true,
  provisional: false,
);

_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
  print("FCM Token: $token");
});
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
  RemoteMessage message) async {
print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");
 }

 void _logNotificationReceivedEvent() {
analytics.logEvent(name: 'notification_received');
 }

 void _logNotificationOpenedAppEvent() {
analytics.logEvent(name: 'notification_opened_app');
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Flutter Push Notification Example'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text('Your app content goes herens'),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```